# Is this a jordan basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

For the linear transformation $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^3)$ defined by $T(x,y,z)=(2x,2y,-x+y+2z)$

I arrived at the basis $(0,0,1),(1,2,0),(1,1,0)$

The matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 &1&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Would this matrix be in Jordan form?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that matrix is in Jordan form. Specifically, it is block diagonal with the following block decomposition: $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\0 & 2\end{pmatrix} \oplus \begin{pmatrix}2 \end{pmatrix}$. Each of these is a Jordan block (of size $2$ and $1$ respectively) for the eigenvalue $2$.

Comment: do you know of a good source for calculating Jordan bases?

Comment: @miles I pretty much only used Friedberg, Insel, Spence's Linear algebra book. Chapter 7 of the text focuses on the Jordan canonical form. (but that was over a year ago, and by now I forgot some of the details lol) I'm afraid I don't have experience with any other sources, nor am I aware of other sources.